# Jquery problem hide show div

Tags: jquery

If i go to http://tourscript.com/hrsportal_last/hotel_details.asp?id=1 and select check in 21 to 24 April i got 2 available rooms.
My problem is when i select at least one room from both (eg 1 single and 1 double) you will see the Book button(the proceed ID) appear but when i select only one i can't get the book button appear ..

The code :

```
$('#roomOptions select').change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#roomOptions select').each(function() {
        var totprice = $(this).val();
        var substr = totprice.split('--');
        alert(substr[1]);
        total+=parseFloat(substr[1]);
    });
    if (total > 0) {
        $('#proceed').show("slow");
    } else {
        $('#proceed').hide("slow");
    }
    $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);
});
```

Before doing the Split it worked even if i selected one or 2 rooms .. i don't know whay doesn't work anymore.
Thank you

Comment: What does the "alert()" show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting a problem through one of the values being undefined. Try this:

```
$('#roomOptions select').each(function() {
    var totprice = $(this).val();
    if(totprice) {
        var substr = totprice.split('--');
        alert(substr[1]);
        total+=parseFloat(substr[1]);
    }
});
```